# Route one network client to VPN server via a Linux gateway server

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ip, routing

I have a Ubuntu server (Ubuntu 10.04.4 LTS) acting as a gateway to my home network. I set up a VPN connection with the [linux-pptp](http://pptpclient.sourceforge.net/howto-ubuntu.phtml) client and now have it as an interface on my home server.

```
ppp0      Link encap:Point-to-Point Protocol  
          inet addr:xx.x.xxx.xxx  P-t-P:10.0.0.1  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1496  Metric:1
          RX packets:6 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:6 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:3 
          RX bytes:60 (60.0 B)  TX bytes:66 (66.0 B)
```

Now I want to route one client in the network with a static IP through this connection instead of the default gateway. I tried to set it up via the `route` command, but it does not work. My current routes:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
192.168.3.1     *               255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 ppp0
10.0.0.1        *               255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 ppp0
87.xxx.xxx.xx   st.ip           255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 eth1
192.168.3.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth2
192.168.2.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1
default         st.ip           0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth1
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say "routed through a proxy?"  A proxy is something you would normally configure in application settings - SOCKS or HTTP, whereas routing is something that defines the next hop for a packet.

Comment: I want to rout all traffic form one client in the network through a external proxy. I can't set the configuration at the client, so I have to do it at the on the gateway server.

Comment: What kind of proxy is it?

Comment: HTTP proxy. I'll update the question. Would VPN be easier? I have control over both machines ...